# Dynamic Split-screen on LEGO Star Wars - The Complete Saga (XBOX 360)

Tags: xbox-360, lego-star-wars

I have seen quite a few cool user-friendly functionality by ***LEGO*** and their games, most impressive of which for me personally was the ***Dynamic Split-screen***.

#### What it is:

I first saw it on some XBOX360 version of *Indiana Jones* or something, but how it basically works is you share one screen for the two players, but as soon as the distance becomes too large between the two players, it starts to split. This is done seamlessly and is really convenient.

#### My question:

My question is whether or not this functionality is available for ***LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga***. Me and my significant other bought this together, in the hopes that it would have this functionality, but we cannot get it to work. Should this be unlocked first or something? Or is it just not there?

Also, could the size of the screen that we play on have an effect on this? If so, how is this determined?

Comment: re: your reddit source, `Note that this list is only for PC games`.

Comment: @TZHX Just noted that, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lego Star Wars was the first of the Lego games from Traveller's Tales, so it's lacking features of its followers. One of these, unfortunately, is the dynamic split screen that made it into more recent releases.